# Is time dilation a mechanical slowdown only?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, time-dilation

I've recently read about the time dilation occurs at very high speeds. But I'm really wondering if it is just a mechanical slowdown of the clock only? What if we use clocks that does not use moving crystals or reflecting light to measure time? Can anyone please make it clear to me?

Comment: You always use some clock to measure time. Time dilatation applies on all kinds of clock known so far, it is an universal effect. If you are not sure how time dilatation works on particular kind of clock, it would probably be better to ask about that particular kind of clock and time dilatation. Your question seem too broad, so only very simple answer ("Yes, it is universal") can be given now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The real meaning of time dilation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53232/)

Comment: See also [Is time dilation an illusion?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/53009/)

Comment: @Irigi So how about biological clocks? Ageing?

Comment: Yes, they too slow down.